# How do I stretch a sub-region of a ID3D11Texture2D?

Tags: directx

My component is given a source `ID3D11Texture2D` buffer that, most of the time, I copy into a staging `ID3D11Texture2D` buffer using `ID3D11DeviceContext::CopyResource`.  These two buffers are the same size.

Sometimes, I want to copy only a rectangular sub-region of the source buffer into the staging buffer and stretch it so the staging buffer is still the same size.  The rectangular sub-region has the same aspect ratio as the source.

The staging buffer is never used for rendering.  It's eventually saved to a media file.

Comment: You can use ``CopySubresourceRegion`` , although you should check the remarks on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476394.aspx) for some known issues. As for stretching, there is no ``StretchBits`` style API in Direct3D 11, but you can either make use of render-to-texture on the GPU if you copy it first to a texture, or you can make use of CPU-based solution like WIC.

Comment: @Chuck, I looked at `CopySubresourceRegion` and it does half the job by copying the part of the source buffer I want. As for stretching it on the GPU, isn't a `ID3D11Texture2D` buffer already a texture? Earlier, I found a CPU solution in C# [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14183861/resizing-and-position-a-sharpdx-sprite#14206645) but I prefer to use only C++ and the GPU for these operations.